# bootstrap resize panel/form and put in the center of the page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to resize my panel named "add product" and put it in the center of my page. My actual html code is this: http://www.bootply.com/32VTpb4Nuk.

I've tried using `center-block` and this css code:

```
.vertical-center-row {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

But I want to resize it and put it in the center, like this image: https://snag.gy/a7MwDn.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.custom{
  width:90%;
  margin:0 auto;
  min-width:350px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row ">
 <div class="panel panel-default custom" >
    <div class="panel-heading">Add product</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Something like this.

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rjxkdfpy/)

PS: Chnage your **panel** width as per your need.

Hope it helps.

Comment: work, when im change size of browser this became very small, how i can setup limit for minimum size ?

Comment: for that you have to use `min-width` property of CSS,  i have updated my answer, check if it works for you.